# IAP detecting SK alert views

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, in-app-purchase

When user taps Buy button, my application issues `addPayment` to `StoreKit`. After that I want to show alert view with "Please wait" and activity indicator. However, SK can also show alert views. Is there any way to detect that SK willShow alert view and hide my alert view, so it will not look ugly(two alert views)?

Comment: It wont show two Alert Views at the same time

Comment: so it will stack all alert views and show always top one?

Comment: it will dismiss your please wait alert and show the alert from StoreKit. I'm not sure whether it will show the Please wait alert again or not. But i'm pity sure that it won't show 2 alerts at the same time

Comment: you can move your comment to answer so I can accept, if you wish. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont show two Alert Views at the same time. As I know it will dismiss your please wait alert and show the alert from StoreKit. I'm not sure whether it will show the Please wait alert again or not. But i'm pity sure that it won't show 2 alerts at the same time